# Matching ENSEMBL ID's to genes that are expressed in one sample but not in the other

Tags: r

So I have some gene expression count data with the columns containing all my samples and each row containing ~60000 genes. I've transformed the data to TPM and changed all non-zero values to a "1" using the following code:

```
df[df != 0] <- 1

ENSEMBL          Sample A  Sample B
ENSG00000210082  1         1
ENSG00000166710  0         1
ENSG00000163220  1         0
...
```

Using this code `df <- df[which(df$SampleA == 1), ]$ENSEMBL` I am able to obtain the ENSEMBL ID's from sample A that contain a 1.

Now I would like to do the same thing except obtain the ENSEMBL ID's that contain 1's that are exclusive to sample A (ie. identify the ENSEMBL ID's that contain a 1 in sample A and 0 in sample B).

Comment: eerrr... if you did not provide the dataset, I think `df[df$SampleA - df$SampleB == 1,]`

Comment: `df[df$\`Sample A\`==1 & df$\`Sample B\`==0, "ENSEMBL"]` should do what you want (or `with(df, ENSEMBL[\`Sample A\`==1 & \`Sample B\`==0])`)

Comment: @StupidWolf R just returns "character(0)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(
  ENSEMBL = c("ENSG00000210082",
               "ENSG00000166710",
               "ENSG00000163220"),
  SampleA = c(1, 0, 1),
  SampleB = c(1, 1, 0)
)

#           ENSEMBL SampleA SampleB
# 1 ENSG00000210082       1       1
# 2 ENSG00000166710       0       1
# 3 ENSG00000163220       1       0
```

base version

```
df[which(df$SampleA == 1 & df$SampleB == 0), ]$ENSEMBL

# [1] "ENSG00000163220"
```

dplyr version

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, SampleA == 1 & SampleB == 0)

#           ENSEMBL SampleA SampleB
# 1 ENSG00000163220       1       0
```

Comment: Both the base version and dplyr versions work but just return "character(0)" when I apply it to my large data frame containing ~60000 ENSEMBL ID's